# How to add time zone lines and GMT offset labels to am4maps.MapChart

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Is it possible to draw lines indicating time zones and show GMT offset labels on a `MapChart`?

We are using `am4geodata_worldHigh` and the Mercator projection (`am4maps.projections.Mercator()`)

Conceptually, we want to produce something like this image (doesn't need to be quite as fancy): [image: sl]

Comment: You mean something like this? https://www.amcharts.com/demos/world-time-zone-map/

Comment: Looks like a winner, thanks @xorspark